# How to generate CMakeLists.txt in Clion when I create project from existing sources?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Idk how to make it automaticly - the only option is to specify where the file is - not to generate it, but I don't wan't to write it by my own, because there are too many source files to include.

Comment: CLion can’t generate a CMakeLists.txt file for an existing project, it doesn’t know what to include and what not to, it doesn’t know what to link etc.

Comment: so maybe i can make some template, that would include all files in directory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the steps that helped me:

1. (Optional) If you have a `CMakeLists.txt` file in your project already but it's incomplete, delete it first.
2. Click on `Tools > CMake > Unload CMake Project`.
3. Open a source file, you will be presented with the option of selecting an existing `CMakeLists.txt` file or creating a new one.
4. Select create new. You will be presented with a list of files in your project which you can select/deselect for inclusion.